# Why can I vote to reopen and also to delete the same question?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete, vote-to-reopen

I just noted I can **vote to reopen** a closed question **and also vote to delete** it. Though probably not a big issue...why?

The system will add the same question in both queues (reopen and delete)? How does automatic deletion will handle this situation? Isn't this completely useless?

Can be used to simply undo the *other* action? If I voted to reopen and I vote to delete then it'll undo reopen vote and cast vote to delete (and vice-versa). I know it's not so intuitive but it may be an use for something otherwise nonsensical (especially because a pending reopen vote will **prevent automatic deletion**).

Comment: The only interlock in the SE software that I know of is that you're not allowed to vote to delete an open question.

Comment: Why do we need to actively stop people from doing both?  If doing both is nonsensical then presumably people won't generally do both.  Are you seeing people do both and are there problems as a result of that behavior?

Comment: @Servy **I** just did it even if not on purpose. I don't know if it can be misused because I can't imagine its implications, I just wonder if it's possible for a reason or simply something too stupid to be considered.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti How can it be mis-used?  What are the negative repercussions of not preventing people from doing this?  What if whatever action the person took *first* was the mistake?  If someone mis-clicked the delete when they meant to reopen you'd stop them from then doing the action they *wanted* to take.  As far as what would happen, that's pretty obvious, one would win.  Either the question will end up being deleted or reopened, and whichever happens first will stop votes from accumulating for the other.

Comment: You can also downvote an accept the same answer. Or answer a question and vote to close it. Or post and then delete your post. It's your *freedom*, don't try to get rid of it.

Comment: If your options change too much based on the state of the question, you run the risk of having an overly-complicated and confusing UI

Comment: @SamIam non necessarily UI must change. A vote to delete may also **undo** vote to reopen (and vice-versa). Not so intuitive but at least it's an use for something that otherwise is a nonsense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no reason to actively prevent people from voting for both.  As for what will happen, it's rather straightforward.  Either the question will end up being reopened, preventing further deletion votes (unless reclosed), it'll be deleted, preventing further reopen votes (unless undeleted), or neither action will collect enough votes.

While there aren't a lot of amazing reasons to allow people to cast both votes, there certainly isn't any compelling reason to *prevent* them from casting both votes, given that, as you yourself said, casting both votes isn't particularly sensible.

Answer (score -3):

You may want to reopen a question because it was closed for the wrong reason, in order to close it for the right reason, then delete it.  We're planning for OCD.

Comment: An astute observation, but not especially important.  It takes a fairly good reason to reopen and close a question that should stay closed anyway, and moderators have to do it in practice; the process is too heavyweight to be practical for the community.